# Heap sort implementation with linked list and arrays

Tags: algorithm, sorting, heap

Heap sort can be implemented using linked list and arrays.

What would be the ideal method of doing it-using linked list or arrays?

What is the time complexity to build heap using arrays and linked lists?Is it O(nlogn) for both?

What is the time complexity for deletion?

Comment: This looks an assignment: Please give your take for each of the questions raised. Where different from "conventional wisdom", show your reasoning.

Answer (score 2):

for array, it is O(nlogn). becoz u can easily fetch element at index i. this characteristic makes it easy to fetch each node's parent and left/right child. and the time complexity for deletion is O(lgn).

for linked list, i think it is a different story. it depends how u define the "next" node. as far as i know, it is more complex than using array.

Answer (score 2):

[Binary Heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap)

Time complexity
in big O notation

```
        Average        Worst case
Space   O(n)           O(n)
Search  N/A Operation  N/A Operation
Insert  O(log n)       O(log n)
Delete  O(log n)       O(log n)
```

So, Time complexity is the same independent of whether it is using linked lists arrays .

Answer (score 0):

Time complexity is the same using either linked lists or arrays, assuming a proper implementation.

I have several implementations of heap sort at my blog. Start [here](http://programmingpraxis.com/2013/01/25/imperative-heaps/) for the traditional array-based version, then follow the links for several linked list versions.

Comment: (Posts shall contain enough information to stay useful even when (external) hyperlinks go stale.) The presentation of `heapify` is *bad*. I neither found  a single `linked list versions` (not even an explicit hyperlink) nor a complexity analysis.