# Heapsort and building heaps using linked list

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, heap

I know that linked list is not a appropriate data structure for building heaps.

One of the answers here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/14584517/5841727) says that heap sort can be done in O(nlogn) using linked list which is same as with arrays.

I think that heapify operation would cost  O(n) time in linked list and we would need (n/2) heapify operations leading to time complexity of O(n^2).

Can someone please tell how to achieve O(nlogn) complexity (for heap sort ) using linked list ?

Comment: If you explain what it means to build a heap using a linked list, then perhaps  this question will make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Stackoverflow URL you mentioned is merely someone's claim (at least when I'm writing this) so based on assumption here is my answer. Mostly when people mention "Time complexity", they mean asymptomatic analysis and finding out the proportion to which time taken by algorithm would increase with increasing size of input ignoring all the constants.

To prove the time complexity with linkedlist lets assume there is a function which returns value for given index (i know linked list don't return by index). For efficiency of this function you'd also need to pass in level but we can ignore that for now since it doesn't have any impact on time complexity.

So now it comes down to analyzing time proportion impact on this function with increasing input size. Now you could imagine that for fixing (heapifying) one node you may have to traverse 3 times max (1. find out which one to swap with requires one traverse to compare one of two possible children, 2. going back to parent for swaping 3. coming back down to the one you just swapped). Now even though it may seem that you are doing max n/2 traversal for 3 times; for asymptomatic analysis this is just equals to 'n'. Now you'll have to do this for log n exactly same way how you do for an array. Therefore time-complexity is O(n log n). On wikipedia time-complexity table for heaps URL https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Summary_of_running_times